# Error when add use to ldap [LDAP: error code 17 - javaSerializedData: attribute type undefined]

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, ldapconnection

I use this code snippets to add user to ldap

```
**public DirContext getLDAPDirContext() throws NamingException {
    final Hashtable envValues = new Hashtable();
    // Assign the JNDI environment values in Map
    envValues.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    envValues.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    envValues.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,dn); // specify the username
    envValues.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,password);           // specify the password
    return new InitialDirContext(envValues);
}
public static void main(String arg[]) throws NamingException {
    LdapNew ldapNew = new LdapNew();
    String groupDN ="ou=user,dc=ldap,dc=***,dc=***";
    BasicAttributes myAttrs = new BasicAttributes(true);  //Basic Attributes
    myAttrs.put("uid","chamils");
    myAttrs.put("objectClass","top");
    myAttrs.put("objectClass","dcObject");
    myAttrs.put("objectClass","organization");
    myAttrs.put("objectClass", "inetOrgPerson");
    myAttrs.put("cn","FNAME LNAME");
    myAttrs.put("displayname", "FNAME LNAMEE");
    myAttrs.put("givenname","Chamilseeee");
    myAttrs.put("sn","Thanthrimudaliged");
    myAttrs.put("mail","*******");
    DirContext ctx = ldapNew.getLDAPDirContext();
    ctx.bind("uid=chamils,ou=user,dc=ldap,dc=****,dc=***",myAttrs);
}**
```

But it gives

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeIdentifierException: [LDAP:
>   error code 17 - javaSerializedData: attribute type undefined];
>   remaining name 'uid=chamils,ou=user,dc=ldap,dc=***,dc=***'    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3110)     at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2987)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:397)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:354)    at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_bind(ComponentContext.java:596)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.bind(PartialCompositeContext.java:183)
>     at
>   com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.bind(PartialCompositeContext.java:173)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)    at
>   LdapNew.main(LdapNew.java:49)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Why is that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `include schema/java.schema` to your OpenLDAP configuration.

Comment: How to do this with recent versions of OpenLDAP?